# Failed to install Eclipse Visual Editor

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, editor

I am trying to install Eclipse visual editor but after getting `"Cannot perform operation. Computing alternate solutions, may take a while 15/15"` it gives the following Details.

```
 Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: Visual Editor 1.5.0.R20101202-1328 (org.eclipse.ve.feature.group 1.5.0.R20101202-1328)
  Missing requirement: Visual Editor Common Data Editor 1.5.0.R20101202-1328 (org.eclipse.ve.cde 1.5.0.R20101202-1328) requires 'bundle com.ibm.icu [3.4.4.1,4.3.0)' but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Visual Editor 1.5.0.R20101202-1328 (org.eclipse.ve.feature.group 1.5.0.R20101202-1328)
    To: org.eclipse.ve.cde [1.3.0,2.0.0)
```

As always thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is saying that the plug-in needs the `com.ibm.icu` plug-in (part of Eclipse) with a version of at least 3.4.4.1 and below 4.3.0.

The current version of `com.ibm.icu` in Eclipse Mars is 54.1.1, the last version of Eclipse with a suitable version was Eclipse 3.6 (very old).

So it looks like the code you have is very out of date.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation greg, I'll use Eclipse WindowBuilder instead.